# ObjectMapper with nested object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have JSON response with an array but is not mapping and throwing error, how I can handle JSON like this

```
{
"total":10,
"count":10,
"start":0,
"items":[
{
"ID":"Hyd4VVGtCNpyLh7JEOL3X-b92yollu9nb3KbweWxNaI=@mailhog.example",
"From":{"Relays":null,"Mailbox":"emails","Domain":"gmail.com","Params":""},
"To":[{"Relays":null,"Mailbox":"test","Domain":"gmail.com","Params":""}],
"Content":{"Headers":{"Content-Type":["multipart/mixed; \tboundary=\"----=_Part_27_47303298.1622881481751\""],
"Date":["Sat, 5 Jun 2021 11:24:42 +0300 (EEST)"],
"From":["test@gmail.com"],
"MIME-Version":["1.0"],
```

I tried to map like this

```
 public static class ResponseDto{
        Integer total;
        Integer count;
        Integer start;
        List<ItemDto> items;
//getters,setters
}
```

```
public static class ItemDto{
        String id;
}
```

and I get an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ID" (class package.api.utils.ApiMailHogUtil$ItemDto), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "id"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 50] (through reference chain: package.api.utils.ApiMailHogUtil$ResponseDto["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->package.api
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Annotate Java property with `@JsonProperty('ID')`.

Comment: @MichalFoksa seems working, thanks. But why total, count, start working without annotate?

Comment: Json and Java properties must match according to configured naming strategy. Default naming strategy is `LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` (e.g. `lowerCamelCase`), thus `total`, `count`, `start` `match`, but `ID`, `Date`, Will not, unless you chose different naming strategy for `ItemDto`, for example `UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` - although you will not avoid `@JasonProperty` annotations completely.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations#jsonnaming

Comment: Search for "objectmapper naming strategy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, `Jackson` doesn't find "ID" field so it throws an exception. You can add `@JsonProperty("ID")` on top of `id` field in `ItemDto`:

```
public static class ItemDto{
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        String id;
        // other fields
}
```